# php variable variables static methods

Tags: php, class, variables, object, static

I have this code:

```
$node = new Node();
```

Now I want to make the 'Node' object dynamic
I get the dynamic name from my config class, this works:

```
$var = Config::instance('modules/activities/config')->get('className');
$node = new $var();
```

But how can I write this in 1 line?
This doensn't work:

```
$node = new Config::instance('modules/activities/config')->get('className')();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague helped my out, I made a static function in my helper class:

```
public static function factory($name = '',  $var = NULL)
{
    $object = new $name((isset($var)) ? $var : '');
    return $object;
}
```

now this is my code (looks a bit messy maybe):

```
$node = Helper::factory(Config::instance('modules/activities/config')->get('className'), $var);
```

Comment: But how are you going to pass arguments to your constructor?

Comment: You could look into ReflectionClass::newInstance() as well

Answer (score 1):

This a new language feature as of PHP 5.4

*Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar()*

See http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the instance method so it returns the object you should be able to use that syntax. Something like :

```
public static function instance()
{
    if (!self::$instance)
        self::$instance = new new Config();
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple. To write them in 1 line just don't use a line break between them like so:

```
$var = Config::instance('modules/activities/config')->get('className');$node = new $var();
```

Comment: I think he wanted to simplify things, not literally jam all of the lines together.